# Using Django as server (backend) for Titanium mobile application?

Tags: android, python, django, twitter-bootstrap, titanium

I am working on building a web interface, Android and iOS applications for the same application.

I have my web interface in Django. There is a multi agent system built using Python in the backend, to which I send and receive messages using zeromq from the django application. The Django application uses bootstrap for the frontend.

I am looking at Titanium to build the mobile applications. Is there a way to use Titanium for the front end, and use Django as my server for the mobile applications as well? Also, I would like to know if I can use the same bootstrap theme I use for the web interface, in my Titanium project as well?

I am new to Titanium, and I am just reading documents now just to get an idea of how it works. This could be a naive question, but I am total newbie and would like to get this information from this forum.

Answer (score 0):

Titanium is a platform in which you can create mobile apps using JavaScript as your main language. However it doesn't use HTML and CSS to render UI of your app. You are creating different view objects by calling `Ti.UI.create*` methods which Titanium translates to native objects. This way look&feel of your app will be as close as possible to native apps.

If you really want to use Bootstrap to style your mobile app, you should take a look on PhoneGap or just create responsive layout which is accessible through mobile browser.

Comment: That is new information to me about Titanium. Thank you for the input. I can see some direction now.